# Creating increasing bins in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, bin

I am attempting to create an array with the number of columns equal to a selected bin size. I want each row in the array to use the values in `t` in sequence. For example, `t` goes from -4 to 4 in intervals of 0.01 seconds. If the bin width is 6, I would like row 1 to be `[-4 -3.99 -3.98 -3.97 -3.96 -3.95]`, and then row 2 would be `[-3.99 -3.98 -3.97 -3.96 -3.95 -3.94]`... and this is repeated until the last row at time = 4 seconds. I got the code starting to work, however I only make it to row 364 before I get a subscript assignment mismatch error. Can anyone help me figure out this error?

```
bin_width = 6;
time_interval = 0.01;
t = -4:time_interval:4;
bin_number = bin_width/2;
t_bin = zeros(length(t),bin_width);

for n = 1:length(t)-bin_width
  t_bin(n,:) = [t(n):time_interval: t(n+bin_width-1)];
  bin_number = bin_number+1;
  n = n+1;
end
```

The error I am getting is

> Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.
>
> Error in Untitled (line 15)
>
> ```
> t_bin(n,:) = [t(n):time_interval: t(n+bin_width-1)];
> ```

Comment: Do you want the last row to start or end with 4, i.e. `[4, 4.01,...]` or `[...3.99, 4]`?

Comment: For `n=364` (not `394`??) what is the value of `[t(n):time_interval: t(n+bin_width-1)]`?

Answer (score 2):

You are running into floating point issues. at the point of failure

```
t(n):time_interval: t(n+bin_width-1)

ans =

   -0.3600   -0.3500   -0.3400   -0.3300   -0.3200
```

where t(n+bin_width)-1 = -0.3100

Here's a work around.

```
bin_width = 6;
time_interval = 0.01;
t = -4:time_interval:4;
bin_number = bin_width/2;
t_bin = zeros(length(t),bin_width);

for n = 1:length(t)-bin_width
    t_bin(n,:)=linspace(t(n),t(n+bin_width-1),6)
end
```

Comment: Or `t_bin(n,:) = t(n:n+bin_width-1);`